# Invoking a jsp from a servlet using request dispatcher?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to invoke a jsp from a servlet as below.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

mine is maven project. jsp is located in below location.

```
SomeProject/src/main/webapp/Hello.jsp
```

But i am getting HTTP ERROR: 404. how can i mention jsp path?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your servlet in the same directory as the jsp page? If not it could be a path problem.

Comment: Where is your jsp? Provide project structure.

Comment: No..jsp and servlet are in different directory..

Answer (score 1):

You should check first if you have access to the jsp in that route, does `http://host:port/context_root/Hello.jsp` work in your web browser?

Comment: I think you have to solve this one first, after that it should work in the servlet. Do you generate a WAR to deploy it on the server? Can you check inside the WAR (with winrar for example) and see if the JSP is there?

Comment: Yes it has...i have copied jsp to war folder...i'm using GWT hosted mode using jetty server..

Comment: Check your web.xml, are there any mappings apart from the servlet you are using?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("Hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and see if it works

Comment: Hi Satya thanks for your reply. tried it did not work..Thanks!

Comment: give me few mins let me create one proj in nb/maven and check

Comment: btw I just now tried with exact settings that you have mentioned and it is working like a charm in Jboss

Comment: But my servlet and jsp are in different directories...Is there any issue with it? Please suggest...

Comment: no I just now pushed a servlet in another package and jsp in another package , it is working as desired

Comment: Is the JSP in a different web app ?

Comment: Is Hello.jsp in your web app's root folder ?

Comment: rickz you are asking me , or , user1016403 ? :)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define the RequestDispatcher method,

Like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("filename.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Make sure your jsp file is in the same directory of the servlet directory.